# Calling view of other state Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am with doubt of like  i call an view inside of other view. I want call the view " menu " in side of state "login" . However is not working

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('menu', {
        abstract:true,
        views: {
            "menu": {
                templateUrl: 'assets/templates/menu/menu.html',
                controller: 'MenuController',
            }
        }
    })
   .state("login", {
       url: '/login',
       views: {
           "": {
               templateUrl: 'assets/templates/LoginTest.html',
               controller: 'LoginController as ctrl',
           },
           "@menu":{    }
       }
   });
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean with calling the view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested state for that.

This tutorial will help you [AngularJS Multi-Step Form Using UI Router](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router)

working plunkr :https://plnkr.co/edit/ar9kbBCdggZxvUGDq5HI?p=preview

```js
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        abstract:true,
        url: '/login',        
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/LoginTest.html',       
        controller: 'LoginController as ctrl'        
    })
        // nested states 
        // each of these sections will have their own view
        // url will be nested (/login/menu)
   .state("login.menu", {
       url: '/menu',       
       templateUrl: 'assets/templates/menu.html',
       controller:  'MenuController'
       }
   );
```

Comment: i need use multiple view

Comment: you want to use multiple view ??